# How can I find all polynomials that fit an equation?

Tags: polynomials, algebra

How can I ask Mathematica to find all polynomial $ f \! $s such that, for a constant $ k $:

$$ f(x) \ f(y) = f(x) + f(y) + f(xy) + k $$

I've solved it on paper and want to check my results. I've tried the following, none of which work:

- `Solve[f[x] f[y] == f[x] + f[y] + f[x y] + k, f]`
- `Solve[f[x] f[y] == f[x] + f[y] + f[x y] + k, f[x]]`
- `Solve[f[x] f[y] == f[x] + f[y] + f[x y] + k, f[z]]`
- `Reduce[f[x] f[y] == f[x] + f[y] + f[x y] + k, f]`
- `f[x_] := Sum[Subscript[c, i] x^i, {i, 0, n}]; Solve[f[x] f[y] == f[x] + f[y] + f[x y] + k, Subscript[c, 0]]`

Comment: Take a look at this quite analogous problem: [Solving functional equations in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31293/solving-functional-equations-in-mathematica/31296#31296)

Comment: I would consider polynomials of increasing degree, and write them in terms of their coefficients. Then solve for the coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `SolveAlways` and to consider a specific value of `n`. Here is $n=4$:

```
f[x_] := Sum[Subscript[c, i] x^i, {i, 0, 4}]
{k, f[x]} /. SolveAlways[f[x] f[y] == f[x] + f[y] + f[x y] + k, {x, y}]
(* {{{-2, 1}, {-2, 1 + x^4}, {-2, 1 + x^3}, {-2, 1 + x^2}, {-2, 1 + x}} *)
```