# How to use Mathematica to find the analytical solutions to functional equations?

Tags: equation-solving

For example, how to use Mathematica to solve the following problems?

find solutions to functional equations like:

The Cauchy's functional equations:
$$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$$

exponential functions:
$$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$$

others:
$$f\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) = \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + 1}$$

Comment: Strongly related [**`31293`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31293/solving-functional-equations-in-mathematica?rq=1)

Comment: As far as I know nobody has found an algorithm solve arbitrary functional equations analytically in a mechanical way. At least nothing I can see in the Kuczma-Choczewski-Ger book 'Iterative Functional Equations', which treats the Cauchy equations on p. 236. There are plenty of ways to go about it numerically though - I've even explored neural network approaches.